# Sorting or populating qualitative data into specified fields from qualitative text?

Tags: data-request, research, parsing

I am trying to process a large amount of qualitative data (a large body of text) into separate fields. I am trying to take a large amount of text and divide or sort it into individual fields.

Is there a way to add "tags" or demarcate the text I want to fall into specific categories I want them to go into?

For instance, there is a large paragraph of text with several pieces of information I want to sort into individual categories (e.g. a name, a year, a small blurb about a company). How can I do that? Thanks